# How to restrict user entering - sign after entering numeric data in uitextfield?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531834/textfieldshouldchangecharactersinrangereplacementstring)

I am facing a situation where user is allowed to enter - sign after entering numeric value. How to restrict/avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSCharacterSet...

For e.g.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
static NSCharacterSet *charSet3 = nil;
if(!charSet3) {
        charSet3 = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789 "] invertedSet];
    } 
    NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet3];
    return (location.location == NSNotFound);
}
```

This will only allow user to enter numeric values to text field and did not take other characters...

Hope this helps..... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to restrict or check if the entered text is number or not..try this

```
if ([textField.text isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {

}
```